# UIImage setter NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiimage, setter

have a problem with object setters in a class.
I have the class GEOImage, where things like description, title etc. will be saved according
to an image.

```
@interface GEOImage : UIImage
{
    NSString *title;
    NSString *imgDescription;
    NSString *latitude;
    NSString *longitude;
    NSDictionary *editInfo;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title, *imgDescription, *latitude, *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *editInfo;
@end
```

Now i try to store a description out of another class:

```
self.chosenImage.imgDescription = @"description";
```

where chosenImage is of type GEOImage.

But i get the error:

> -[UIImage setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x939d220
>   2011-12-05 10:59:40.621 GeoPG[511:17c03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage setTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x939d220'

If I'm looking in the debugger, the chosenImage is not NULL, and its been displayed correct in an image view.

Greets
s4lfish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can safely infer that `chosenImage` is not `nil`; if it were `nil`, sending it a message would simply do nothing, not crash.

(Also, I'm assuming that you meant `title` rather than `imgDescription` in your usage sample, or that you implemented `setImgDescription:` to set the `title` in turn.)

There are two possibilities:

#### Dead object

You created the image you stored to `chosenImage` as a GEOImage, but then it died while you were holding on to it. Subsequently, a UIImage (as identified in the exception message) was created at the same address, so the pointer you still hold now points to a UIImage. You sent a message to it that only works on GEOImages, but it's only a UIImage, so it doesn't respond to the message, which is the exception.

The cause of an object dying while you're holding it is that either you didn't retain it somewhere where you should have, or you released it somewhere where you shouldn't have. Or possibly both.

Run your app under Instruments with the Zombies template. It will raise a flag when you hit this crash, and you can then investigate by clicking the button in that flag. Look at all of the Release and Autorelease events, starting from the end, to find the one that shouldn't be there; then, if the release itself is unwarranted, take it out, or if it should be balanced by a previous retain, put one of those in.

One possible cause of the crash is that you declared the `chosenImage` property as `assign`, but you should have declared it as `retain`/`strong`. If this is the problem, your Instruments findings will support it.

Long-term, you should convert to ARC, which eliminates 90% of the cases where this problem could happen.

#### You never created a GEOImage in the first place

Just because you declared that `chosenImage` will hold a pointer to a GEOImage doesn't mean it does. You can assign any object pointer there, and in many cases, the compiler doesn't know if it isn't actually a GEOImage.

(They introduced a feature called “related result types” in a future version of Clang that should make this much less likely.)

At a guess, I'd say you're doing something like this:

```
self.chosenImage = [GEOImage imageNamed:@"blah blah blah"];
```

or this:

```
self.chosenImage = [imagePicker takePicture];
```

There is no reason to expect `takePicture` to return a GEOImage (how should it know that's what you want?), and it's likely that `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` (assuming you simply inherit it) won't, either. Unless you create a GEOImage instance yourself, using `alloc` and an initializer, you cannot assume that any UIImage you get will be a GEOImage.

The solution is to make it easy to create a GEOImage from a UIImage (which will involve wrapping [this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/initWithCGImage%3ascale%3aorientation%3a)), and then do that.

---

Once you have a live (not dead) GEOImage (not UIImage) in your `chosenImage` property, it will work.

Comment: I create the GEOImage with the info key from the ImagePickerController: `GEOImage *chosenImage =[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];`

Comment: This doesn't create an GEOImage? I also use ARC and the properties of the GEOImage are `(nonatomic, retain)` . I also tried the Zombie template, but the app crashes as usual with the same error message. There is no other log output from a Zombie.

Comment: @s4lfish: The image picker controller gives you a UIImage, not a GEOImage; there is no way for it to know that you want it to create a GEOImage, so it doesn't. As I said in the answer, just because you declare that the variable will hold a pointer to a GEOImage doesn't mean it will; you declared that, and then you put a pointer to a UIImage into the variable instead. My term for this is “lying to the compiler”; the fix begins with restoring truth by correcting the declaration.

Comment: @s4lfish: Once you correct the declaration, the compiler will begin warning you that you're trying to do GEOImage things with a UIImage. This is correct; you always were, which is the problem. You'll need to create a GEOImage from the UIImage for those things to work. You should probably do that right after getting the UIImage.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can u give me an example how to create an GEOImage from an UIImage? I'm quite new to iOS programming. I tried to initwithCGImage or something like this, but that didn't work. Probably because the image i get from the Picker is still an UIImage ... but i found no option to initwithUIImage.

Comment: @s4lfish: You will need to write a method to create a GEOImage from a UIImage yourself. I described how that method should work in my answer. If you have a problem implementing it, you should ask a new question about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it was like Peter said: I never created an GEOImage. I now I create the GEOImage like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSURL *imgURL = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    [self createGEOImage:imageRef info:info imageURL:imgURL];
}
```

And the method called with the imageRef:

```
- (void)createGEOImage:(CGImageRef*)imageRef info:(NSDictionary*)info imageURL:(NSURL*)imgURL{
    GEOImage *geoImage = [[GEOImage alloc]initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    geoImage = info;
    geoImage = imgURL;
}
```

Thanks for your help!